# JMeter in combination constant throughput timer and constant timer

Tags: timer, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I use JMeter for web testing.
Actually I use a constant throughput timer to keep the frequency constant. However, in one case I need an additional constant timer because I need to wait a certain time between two requests.

The constant throughput timer delays the request to ensure that JMeter does not perform more requests than specified. However, I am not sure how JMeter handles the situation when there is an additional constant timer after a request.

Can anyone explains this?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of "explanation" you're looking for?

1. Timers are executed before each [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in their [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)
2. Timers are executed upside down one by one
3. Constant Throughput Timer will try to slow down JMeter's throughput to the defined value by sleeping for the period of time before executing the Sampler if needed

So everything depends on:

1. Application response time
2. Order of the timers
3. How exactly you configured the Constant Throughput Timer (there are 5 items in the "Calculate throughput based on" dropdown

If you want to "wait a certain time between two requests" the most straightforward option is using [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler

Comment: My question is whether two timers influence each other? In my case, I have 20 requests per minute. Between the second and the third request, I want to wait 45 seconds with a constant timer, and between the sixth and the seventh request, I want to wait 13 seconds again. So I can see that JMeter is sending ~ 20 requests per minute. But if I add a constant throughput timer with a maximum of 22 RQM, JMeter sends only 15 requests per minute.

So how does a second timer change the behavior of another timer?